# Style is messing up on horizontal resize

Tags: html, wordpress, css

When I resize the page horizontally below 800px it messes up the styling.

Can someone take a look at what is going on?
Why is it happening?

It is wordpress Geotheme.

Thank you.

"I just fixed it in a different way. I found that @media(max-width:800px) was applying a different set of styles and those caused the problem Thanks anyway. "

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a margin:auto on in inner divs. That means that the divs will always try to fill the space.

add overflow:auto on header.
remove margin:auto on the correct locations

The design itself is ... too complicated. You should really simplify it and separate the margin and the areas where you put content.

```
<div id="page_head" style="width:800px; margin:auto; margin-top:20px; border:1px solid black; height:100px; position:relative; padding-left:200px; box-sizing:border-box;">
     <div style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; background-color:red; width:100px; height:100px;">Image</div>
</div>
<div id="page_content" style="width:800px; margin:auto; margin-top:20px; border:1px solid black; height:100px; position:relative;">

</div>
<div id="page_footer" style="width:800px; margin:auto; margin-top:20px; border:1px solid black; height:100px; position:relative;">

</div>
```

To this, if you add and outer div you can also further control it.
See [JsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/CCKnG/).

Comment: I would really appreciate the example.

Comment: Alright. I think it is also because of percentage widths. I checked with demo version of Geotheme. I could try disabling percent width styling.

Comment: In this case you would find it.. hard. The style is so complicated. Try and simplify it by adding a class that will remove the problematic stuff and just do it yourself. Hope I helped :)

Comment: I just fixed it in a different way. I found that @media(max-width:800px) was applying a different set of styles and those caused the problem Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your layout is based on floats and they get pushed down when resizing. Try giving your wrapper a: min-width: 800px